How can I remove a specific trade from a villager in Minecraft?
I'm trying to make it so that Mason villagers are less likely/incapable of selling some of the colors of glazed terracotta, however I don't want to lose the ones that already have those trades, I just want this to apply to new villagers. Is that possible? I've tried some /data remove commands but none seem to have removed the trade/change the chance of having that trade.

What commands did you use exactly? Please have a look at the [minecraft-commands] tag that I ..well, tagged your question with.

I didn´t get any of them to work, I also don´t know much about commands so I just followed some other commands I saw in other forums but changing them to my items. However none of them seem to work. Basically /data remove entity @e(type:villager) trade:(insertitemhere)

Instead of trying to remove trades from a villager why not spawn a villager with specific trades? You could add all trades except the glazed terracotta to make it feel authentic.
From the source :
/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {VillagerData:{profession:farmer,level:2,type:plains},CustomName:"\"John\"",Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:emerald,Count:1},sell:{id:wheat,Count:1},rewardExp:0b,maxUses:9999999}]}}

This command will spawn a villager named John who sells 1 wheat for 1 emerald.
Source
